# Python 3.10 RuntimeWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, architecture, runtime

My Python version is 3.10.12, and some parts of my project have the following structure:

```
shapy/
    ...
    regressor/
        ...
        human_shape/
             ...
             data/
                 ...
                 datasets/
                     ...
                     openpose.py
                     __init__.py
                 structures/
                     ...
                     keypoints.py
                     __init__.py
                 __init__.py
             __init__.py
```

I want to run `openpose.py`, so I use the command in `regressor` folder:

```
python -m human_shape.data.datasets.openpose
```

Then I got an error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py:126: RuntimeWarning: 'human_shape.data.datasets.openpose' found in sys.modules after import of package 'human_shape.data.datasets', but prior to execution of 'human_shape.data.datasets.openpose'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
```

I know this problem indicates that the `human_shape.data.datasets` package has been found in `sys.modules` before importing the `human_shape.data.datasets.openpose` module,
but I've tried to check `sys.modules`, and there are no related packages.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Absolute Imports.

Add the following code at the beginning of your openpose.py file to print the contents of sys.modules. This can help you identify where the package is being imported.

```
import sys
print(sys.modules)
```

Also make sure there are no circular imports in your code, as they can lead to unpredictable behavior. Circular imports occur when two or more modules depend on each other.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Because this is the source code proposed by others, its scale is very large. If I want to use absolute import, it will interfere with too many packages. It can only use relative import.